# I need to show calendar one at a time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap here is my code.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group date mg-check-in">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="date" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Check In">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group date mg-check-out">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="date" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Check Out">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script. I am using datepicker js here too.
 * http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$ (function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: when I click in the datepicker it will show the calendar, I need to show each calendar one at a time for check in and check out. Sorry if confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to download the latest version of plugin assets from this [Link](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) and then try the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="input-group date mg-check-in">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" name="date" id="dp1" placeholder="Check In">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
  <div class="input-group date mg-check-out">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" name="date" id="dp2" placeholder="Check Out">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#dp1, #dp2').datepicker({
   autoclose: true
 })
```

Check working example here at [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/pbBdxY?editors=1010)

Hope it helps you.. 
Enjoy :)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, but in your codepen link when I click check in and check out there's no calendar showing.

Comment: Hi! Still not working but I will try your code. Thanks!

Comment: Your Welcome, Upvote the answer if find it useful.. Thank you :)